# How do I prevent a method from being called more than once

Tags: java, testng

Let's say I have these methods

```
public class AuthProvider {
    protected AWSCredentials obtainAuth() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key1", "");
        return credentials;
    }
}

public class Uploader extends AuthProvider {
    public void uploadFile() {
        obtainAuth();
        //code to upload file
    }
}
```

Then I have my `TestNg` test class as below

```
public class T1 {
    @Test
    public void runTest1() {
        Uploader uploader = new Uploader();
        uploader.uploadFile();
    }
}

public class T2 {
    @Test
    public void runTest1() {
        Uploader uploader = new Uploader();
        uploader.uploadFile();
    }
}
```

Now if I run `T1` and `T2` as part of test suite it will run the `obtainAuth()` method twice (Once in `T1` and Once in `T2`). Since I'm running both tests as part of the same suite it should only run the `obtainAuth()` method and store the returned value which is `AWSCredentials` in a `static` way.

I tried instantiating `obtainAuth()` in a `static` way by declaring a static class level field in `Uploader` class. But it didn't work.

Comment: Depends on the testing framework but they usually have a setUp() method that runs before the first test in the suite and a tearDown() method that runs after the last test in the suite. Try to look up setup/teardown in the documentation of your testing framework.

Comment: I added it in `beforeSuite()`. It works. But I want to solve it in some other way?

Comment: Sure, if you want to prevent multiple calls in the application as well you would solve this in the application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you add an abstraction. What prevents you from putting a check into your AuthProvider that checks if it already did do its job?

In other words: rework your method to allow for multiple calls; but only the first does something; the other are no-ops: or even simpler:

```
public class AuthProvider {
  private static final AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key1", "");

  protected AWSCredentials obtainAuth() {
    return credentials;
  }
```

But well, what would hinder then from making the whole thing static ...

Comment: Do you mean initialize the variable and do a `null` check?

Comment: Not even a null check. I guess one call should happen in any case. Keep in mind that lazy init is a form of **optimization**; and thus can be premature and not helpful.

Comment: Thanks and makes sense. Earlier when I had everything in one class I mean both auth and uploader in one class, I made the auth static and `testng` didn't like it for some reasons. I don't know why. Now that I separated it works well

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do this

```
public class AuthProvider {
    private static AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key1", "");
    protected AWSCredentials obtainAuth() {
        return credentials;
    }
}
```